# Post query from client-side Javascript using Express (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm developing a web app using Express. On one of my pages I have a table filled with data and I want users to be able to modify the data. I use `contenteditable` (HTML5) to make the data editable (DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/k854hsae/5/)

I have a Javascript method to submit whatever has been written when the Enter key is pressed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $editableTd = $('td[contenteditable]');
    $editableTd.bind('keyup', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
           $(this).blur();
           // SAVE NEW DATA TO DATABASE
        }

    });
});
```

I use MongoDB. I want to save the new data to the database every time a cell is modified (so no "submit button"). I'm not quite sure on how to pass the information along in Express. From the examples I've seen, they all use Forms with the following syntax in Jade:

```
 form#formAddUser(name="adduser",method="post",action="/adduser")
```

But I don't know how I can POST using `contenteditable`. Is there a way to "call" server-side JS from client-side JS?

Comment: Cracks me up how these idiots down vote on SO. You take the time to post an elaborate question, and they down vote without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .post() method to send ajax post request from client-side JS to server-side JS.